# Is there a maximum number of service accounts that a project can have in the google cloud platform?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'd like to dynamically generate service accounts/clients and there is a possibility that I would generate a lot of them. Is there a maximum number of client ids / service accounts that a google cloud platform project can have?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it's a question for Google support.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. All of the "Community forums" point to stack overflow and I didn't see any way to send a support message so I pinged 'em on google plus. We'll see if that works.

Comment: Best might be to use https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine and/or other google groups listed at https://cloud.google.com/support/ under "Community Support".  Yes, we love StackOverflow, but some support issues are just not suitable for it, which is why we still have the various google groups in question!-)

Answer (score 6):

I know this is too late but came across this [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/faq#what_is_the_maximum_number_of_service_accounts_i_can_have_in_a_project) in Google cloud docs which answers this question as follows:

> You can create 100 service accounts in a project. Contact your account manager 
>   if you need to create more than 100 service accounts in a project.

Comment: This FAQ document is no longer there?  But this page https://goo.gle/service-account-limits states the same: the default _quota_ is 100 service accounts.  You can request a quota increase if you need more.  The page doesn't state the max limit, but...i feel pretty confident that the upper limit is much higher than 100.  !

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a limit on the number of service accounts, but there is a [limit to the number of refresh tokens](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#toomanytokens) for a given service account:

> There is a limit to the total number of refresh tokens that your service account can have at any one point in time. Currently, this limit is 600. If this limit is reached, Google Compute Engine will not be able to create an instance which requires a new refresh token, and you will get a `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TOO_MANY_TOKENS` error. For example, if you have reached the refresh token limit, and you attempt to create an instance with a new, unique set {default, scope1, scope2, scope3, scope4), the action fails and you will receive the `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TOO_MANY_TOKENS` error.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [limit](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/faq#what_is_the_maximum_number_of_service_accounts_i_can_have_in_a_project) on the number of service accounts per project.

However, you could increase this limit through the [quota page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota).

In your project's [quota page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) edit the following to increase limit on the number of service accounts per project.

```
'Quota type': All quotas
'Service' : Identity and Access Management (IAM) API  
'Metric'  : Service Account Count
```